# About xlwings, the API for Excel VBA to use Python

Tags: python, excel, vba, xlwings

When I follow the instruction of xlwings up to:

```
Sub MyMacro()
     RunPython ("import mymodule; mymodule.rand_numbers()") 
End Sub
```

It gives me error like: *can't find mymodule*. My understanding is this should be an object from xlwings.

Why can't Excel find it and how should I correct this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `PYTHONPATH` setting to the folder where `mymodule` is. Per default it expects it to be in the same directory as your Excel file, see the [docs](http://docs.xlwings.org/vba.html#settings).

Comment: Sorry, I am very new to learn this, could you give me a favor to tell me how to find "where my module is?" I thought it should in the script xlswings.

Comment: I suggest you download the `fibonacci` example from the homepage, unzip it (!), then run it. the fibonacci Excel file and the `fibonacci.py` need to be in the same directory - `fibonacci.py` is what you call `mymodule` in your sample.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I think I got how to run the amazing xlwings, but when I try the "mymodule.py" again from "docs" it gives me this error about function int(): 
Error
---------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                line 7, in rand_numbers    n = int(Range('Sheet1','B1').value)  # Write desired dimensions into Cell B1TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'        Can you do me one more favor about why does it give this error?